# Cannot CSV Load a file in Colab Using tf.compat.v1.keras.utils.get_file

Tags: csv, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have mounted my GDrive and have csv file in a folder. I am following the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv). However, when I issue the tf.keras.utils.get_file(), I get a ValueError As follows.

```
data_folder = r"/content/drive/My Drive/NLP/project2/data"
import os
print(os.listdir(data_folder))
```

It returns:

```
['crowdsourced_labelled_dataset.csv',
 'P2_Testing_Dataset.csv',
 'P2_Training_Dataset_old.csv',
 'P2_Training_Dataset.csv']

TRAIN_DATA_URL = os.path.join(data_folder, 'P2_Training_Dataset.csv')
train_file_path = tf.compat.v1.keras.utils.get_file("train.csv", TRAIN_DATA_URL)
```

But this returns:

```
Downloading data from /content/drive/My Drive/NLP/project2/data/P2_Training_Dataset.csv
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-5bd642083471> in <module>()
      2 TRAIN_DATA_URL = os.path.join(data_folder, 'P2_Training_Dataset.csv')
      3 TEST_DATA_URL = os.path.join(data_folder, 'P2_Testing_Dataset.csv')
----> 4 train_file_path = tf.compat.v1.keras.utils.get_file("train.csv", TRAIN_DATA_URL)
      5 test_file_path = tf.compat.v1.keras.utils.get_file("eval.csv", TEST_DATA_URL)


6 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in _parse(self)
    382         self.type, rest = splittype(self._full_url)
    383         if self.type is None:
--> 384             raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
    385         self.host, self.selector = splithost(rest)
    386         if self.host:

ValueError: unknown url type: '/content/drive/My Drive/NLP/project2/data/P2_Training_Dataset.csv'
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/get_file), this will be the outcome of a call to the function `tf.compat.v1.keras.utils.get_file`.

```
tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    fname,
    origin,
    untar=False,
    md5_hash=None,
    file_hash=None,
    cache_subdir='datasets',
    hash_algorithm='auto',
    extract=False,
    archive_format='auto',
    cache_dir=None
)
```

> By default the file at the url origin is downloaded to the cache_dir ~/.keras, placed in the cache_subdir datasets, and given the filename fname. The final location of a file example.txt would therefore be ~/.keras/datasets/example.txt.
>
> **Returns:**
>   Path to the downloaded file

Since you already have the data in your drive, there's no need to download it again (and IIUC, the function is expecting an accessible URL). Also, there's no need of obtaining the file name from a function call because you already know it.

Assuming the drive is mounted, you can replace your file paths as below:

```
train_file_path = os.path.join(data_folder, 'P2_Training_Dataset.csv')
test_file_path = os.path.join(data_folder, 'P2_Testing_Dataset.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you. Now when I issue with while space in my filename: !head {train_file_path}, it returns head: cannot open '/content/drive/My' for reading: No such file or directory
head: cannot open 'Drive/NLP/project2/data/P2_Training_Dataset.csv' for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: Probably something to do with the space in the file name. Replace `data_folder` to be `data_folder = r"/content/drive/My\ Drive/NLP/project2/data"`

Comment: No, When I do that, then "os.listdir(data_folder)
"   returns: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/My\\ Drive/CSC791_NLP_NCSU/project2/data'

Comment: That backslash is only required when you're executing linux commands. When you're calling python functions that is unnecessary - it will work with what you originally had.

Comment: I am sorry. I tried it it does not work either way!

Comment: Probably you haven't mounted the drive to colab then. Would `os.listdir("/content/drive/My Drive/")` work?

Comment: That was a good hint! I did os.chdir("/content/drive/My Drive") and now it works, becuase it is skipping that folder My Drive. It really shouldn't act like that... somethings not write!

Comment: @chikitin it takes time to get used to a new platform :)